# Where did my Reputation go?

Tags: support, reputation

I had over 200 reputation and now (next to my username) it says I have only around 170!?

Is this a bug, cause it has happened before to me. I have received no warnings about anything going weird, so what is up?
I like my reputation :(

Answer (score 6):

There are a few possible causes of this. You probably haven't been downvoted 15 times (or cast 30 downvotes yourself) without knowing, so I'll skip those "possible" causes and cover more likely ones instead.

#### Serial Upvoting Reversal

If you got many upvotes from the same person in a short time, then the system will identify this as serial upvoting and remove the reputation associated with it. If this happened, you should see *serial upvoting reversed* on [your reputation page](https://askubuntu.com/users/136381/packpatfan?tab=reputation). (I cannot see that, even if it is there--most negative reputation changes to your profile can only be seen by you, and moderators.)

#### Unaccepts and Unupvotes

After a user votes on a post, their vote is locked in after a short time. But they can change it if the post has been edited. Furthermore, there is no lock-in of accepts. So if the creator of a question marked your answer as accepted, they can unaccept it at any time (causing you to lose the 15 reputation you gained from your answer being accepted).

Two unaccepts would result in a loss of 30 reputation. Or 3 unupvotes on answers.

#### Deletion

If you've delete a question or answer you've posted, then you'll lose any reputation (both positive and negative) associated with it. This also happens if your posts are deleted by someone else, or automatically by the system. For example, if you had an upvoted question that was closed, it may have been subsequently deleted.

One or more questions you answered (and earned reputation from) may have been deleted. When a question is deleted, all its answers are deleted too (though they will come back automatically if the question is undeleted). Alternatively, your answer may itself have been deleted. You can delete your own answers, but sometimes answers are deleted by moderators, too.

A common reason moderators delete some upvoted answers is when a question is marked as a duplicate. If your answer doesn't provide any information beyond what is provided by answers in the master question, it may be deleted rather than merged. Of course, a question can be closed as a duplicate with removing or merging any answers. However, sometimes answers are deleted so that the question that's been closed as a duplicate will automatically redirect to the master question.

#### Migration

If you asked or answered a question that was migrated to another Stack Exchange site, you lose any reputation associated with it here, and gain that reputation on the target site.

(The reputation becomes associated with your account there only if that account is associated with your account here. If you have an account but it's not associated, you'll only gain the reputation on the target site by associating it. If you don't have an account, you'll gain the reputation on the target site by registering there and associating the account there with your AU account here. This can be accomplished by using the same OpenID to log in to both accounts. Or you can use different OpenIDs but make sure they're all listed in [your single network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2427963/packpatfan).)

#### *How to find out?*

Usually, you can determine the reason for a loss of reputation by checking [your reputation page](https://askubuntu.com/users/136381/packpatfan?tab=reputation). Often it's necessary **to check the box at the bottom labeled *show removed posts***. That will probably show what happened to cause the loss of rep.

If you still cannot determine the cause of your recent rep loss by looking at your reputation page with *show removed posts* checked, please update your question to let us know.

If that doesn't reveal it, you can check your reputation audit at https://askubuntu.com/reputation. (This URL shows different information for each user.)

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any of these things displayed??

Comment: @packpatfan Did you see my answer?  You need to enable "Show deleted posts" on your reputation page.

Comment: hmm....that `/reputation` page doesn't show major `-` anywhere, just the occasional one where I changed my selected answer... Should I post the output of that file?

Comment: Oh well...It doesn't really matter that much. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @packpatfan Posting the contents of your `/reputation` page will reveal info about your rep changes that you may or may not want to make public (or which you might be perfectly fine with people seeing), but sure, if you want to post it, go ahead! Either way, a moderator can probably (at some point) explain the reason for the lost rep. But if we can figure it out first, that's even better. (So it's up to you. Posting it, or not posting it, will neither guarantee that we'll be able to quickly figure out the source of the lost rep, *nor* prevent your question from eventually being answered.)

Comment: ok. Well, it doesn't really matter, but thanks for all your help!

Comment: @EliahKagan jrg Said he can't see this stuff, so I doubt anyone except the OP himself will be able to see what happened.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tab in your profile called "Reputation".  You can see a history of all reputation changes there.

[image]

Now from what *I* can see you haven't had any big changes recently.  I don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts however, so those might be causing the problem. Scroll down to the bottom of your reputation page and check the checkbox titled "Show removed posts"

[image]

If you have a answer or question with a score of 5 or more you will keep that reputation even if the post is deleted, however any answers or questions with a score *lower* than 5 will take their reputation with them if they get deleted.

Comment: I know how to look for this, but I can't see anything noting deleted posts. How would I find this?

Comment: @EliahKagan I have checked it, I just don't see anything noting any of the things you listed

Comment: @packpatfan When you check that box, does *anything* new appear in your list of reputation-generating events, at all? Please note that you may have to expand previous days to check, unless you know the decrease in reputation was very recent.

Comment: Try reloading the page as well.

Comment: ok, I'll try that...nothing happened

Comment: @packpatfan What did you try? Reloading the page? Checking for any differences at all? Checking for negative reputation generating events by expanding previous days?

Comment: Try un-ticking some of the arrows.